# Managing serial port names in Mac OSX with symlinks

Tags: macos, serial-port, usb, tty

I'm wondering if someone knows a way to manage USB serial port names in OSX? For example, whenever I connect a specific device serial number I always want it's serial /dev/device1

I know in linux you can do this by /etc/udev/rules.d/49-persistent-usb.rules and adding a device rule like `SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{serial}=="1234567", SYMLINK+="device1"`

What is the Mac equivalent? Thanks in advance.

...maybe this is as easy as just a normal symbolic link for /dev/tty.usb > /dev/device1

Comment: As of OSX 10.11 El Capitan, symbolic links in `/dev/` fall under SIP and can't be easily done.   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its as easy as:

$sudo ln -sf /dev/oldname /dev/newname

Comment: In Yosemite, these links are getting deleted on reboot. Curious to know if anyone knows if something has changed since the OS X 10.10 release?

Comment: FYI: this doesn't work in High Sierra ("Operation not permitted")

Comment: The "Operation not permitted" is from System Integrity Protection https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899